# Error Importing a variable from one Python script to another

Tags: python

I have two Python (3.8) scripts located in the same folder.

The first **lookup.py** is simply:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import os
from getimp import session0
print (session0)
```

The second script **getimp.py** identifies a cookie and sets it as a variable which is imported into the first script. I have omitted some of the code here, but hopefully have the critical parts.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import os
import json
import base64
import sqlite3
import shutil
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import win32crypt # pip install pypiwin32
from Crypto.Cipher import AES # pip install pycryptodome

def get_chrome_datetime(chromedate):
    """Return a `datetime.datetime` object from a chrome format datetime
....

....
    # you can also search by domain, e.g thepythoncode.com
    cursor.execute("""
    SELECT host_key, name, value, creation_utc, last_access_utc, expires_utc, encrypted_value
    FROM cookies
    WHERE name like '%user_id%'""")
    # get the AES key
    key = get_encryption_key()
    for host_key, name, value, creation_utc, last_access_utc, expires_utc, encrypted_value in cursor.fetchall():
        if not value:
            decrypted_value = decrypt_data(encrypted_value, key)
        else:
            # already decrypted
            decrypted_value = value
        print(f"""
        {decrypted_value}
        ===============================================================""")
        
    session0 = decrypted_value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I run **getimp.py** on its own it generates the correct result but when I run **lookup.py** I get an error:

```
  File "lookup", line 4, in <module>
    from getimp import session0
ImportError: cannot import name 'session0' from 'getimp' (D:\Documents\ptest\getimp.py)
```

Am I losing the variable once the script **getimp.py** finishes?

Comment: I don't see a top-level `session0` variable in `getimp.py`. There's a `session0` variable inside the function `get_chrome_datetime()`, but that variable shouldn't be visible outside that function.

Comment: your session0 variable seems to be local to the `get_chrome_datetime` function, try making it global

Comment: (I'm new to this!) So how do I get that value from inside the function to the top level so that presumably it can then be passed on? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the variable`session0` is defined inside the scope of `get_chrome_datetime`  and therefore can not be addressed from import.

Try importing the function and create the variable inside the scope of the active script.

Inside 'get_chrome_datetime' change  `session0=decrypted_value` into `return decrypted_value`

and in **lookup.py** :

```
import os
from getimp import get_chrome_datetime
print (get_chrome_datetime(argument))
```

Comment: I can't quite get this yet. How do I define the variable 'argument'?

Comment: in getimp.py you give define 'get_chrome_datetime' to take an argument that you call 'chromedate', just give what 'chromedate' should be instead of argument

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `session0` is defined inside the function.

I would suggest the following

```
session0 = None
def get_chrome_datetime(chromedate):
  global session0
  ... (your code here)
```

Also you should call the function outside of `if __name__ == '__main__'` because when you're importing a module, the `__name__` wouldn't be `"__main__"`

Comment: I understand the first part, but what do I need to do to if __name__ == "__main__":
    main() ?

Comment: __name__ == "__main__" is used when you are running the script, not importing it. It's used to prevent your code from running when you're importing it from an other file. This one really depends on what you're trying to do, since you can return the session0 value & simply import that function instead of importing the variable

Comment: No, I would not run this script on its own, only imported into **lookup.py**. So sounds like I can delete those lines. They are only there because I adapted the code from https://www.thepythoncode.com/

Comment: Also, main() is going to run the get_chrome_datetime function ? If so, you can remove the if __name__ == ....
Or you can make your function return the value session0